# is_int and GET or POST

Tags: php

Why does `is_int` always return false in the following situation?

```
echo $_GET['id']; //3
if(is_int($_GET['id']))
    echo 'int'; //not executed
```

Comment: is_int() checking variable's type, not contents

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Why does is_int always return false?

Because `$_GET["id"]` is a string, even if it happens to contain a number.

Your options:

- Use the [filter](http://php.net/filter) extension. `filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` will return an integer typed variable if the variable exists, is not an array, represents an integer and that integer is within the valid bounds. Otherwise it will return `false`.
- Force cast it to integer `(int)$_GET["id"]` - probably not what you want because you can't properly handle errors (i.e. "id" not being a number)
- Use [`ctype_digit()`](http://www.php.net/ctype_digit) to make sure the string consists only of  numbers, and therefore is an integer - technically, this returns `true` also with very large numbers that are beyond `int`'s scope, but I doubt this will be a problem. **However**, note that this method will not recognize negative numbers.

Do not use:

- [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) because it will also recognize float values (1.23132)

Comment: keep in mind that e.g. `is_numeric('47.11e5')` returns true. I.e. is_numeric() doesn't only test for integers in decimal representation.

Comment: @Volker yup, I just had the same thought. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Because HTTP variables are always either strings, or arrays.  And the elements of arrays are always strings or arrays.

You want the `is_numeric` function, which will return true for `"4"`.  Either that, or cast the variable to an int `$foo = (int) $_GET['id']`...

Answer (score 2):

Checking for integers using `is_int($value)` will return false for strings.

Casting the value -- `is_int((int) $value)` -- won't help because strings and floats will result in false positive.

`is_numeric($value)` will reject non numeric strings, but floats still pass.

But the thing is, a float cast to integer won't equal itself if it's not an integer. So I came up with something like this:

```
$isInt = (is_numeric($value) && (int) $value == $value);
```

It works fine for integers and strings ... and some floating numbers.

But unfortunately, this will not work for some float integers.

```
$number = pow(125, 1/3); // float(5) -- cube root of 125
var_dump((int) $number == $number); // bool(false)
```

But that's a whole different question.

Answer (score 1):

How i fixed it:

```
$int_id = (int) $_GET["id"];

if((string)$int_id == $_GET["id"]) {
echo $_GET["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$_GET['id']` is a ***string*** like other parts of query string. You are not converting it to integer anywhere so `is_int` return false.

Comment: doesn't `inval()` always return an int, so isn't the `is_int()` check superfluous?

Comment: @Tom Haigh: That is just an example, just put up the code so that condition return true, a problem posed by OP. And yes it is redundant; either should be used but I wonder what OP is up to.

Comment: Omg, how stupid is that solution? Sorry, but that makes no sense at all. Casting to `int` within the `is_int()` function is probably the worst example you'll find in here.

Comment: @GuidoH why ? he answered the question ?

Comment: That's absolutely no solution! If you cast a variable to `int` within the `is_int()` function, it'll **always** return `true`.

Comment: @GuidoH: Who said it is a solution? It is just an example on how to make the condition resolve to true. See my comment for Tom Haigh. But i rather remove that part because it creates confusion for you and the like. And you should mind your language :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably stored as a string in the $_GET, cast it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Because $_GET is an array of strings.

To check if the get parameter contains an integer you should use `is_numeric()`

Answer (score 0):

The dirty solution I'm using is this:

```
$val = trim($_GET['id']);
$cnd = ($val == (int)$val);
echo $cnd ? "It's an int" : "Not an int";
```

Apart from the obvious (ugly code that hides its workings behind specifics of the php engine), does anybody know cases where this goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Prabably best way to check if value from GET or POST is integer is check by preg_match

```
if( preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_GET['id'] ){
   echo "is int";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly try the `intval()` which can be used  to test the value of your var. e.g

```
If(intval($_GET['ID']==0)
```

The function will check if the var is integer and return `TRUE` if not `FALSE`