# Check if variable is a number and positive integer in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, variables, numbers, integer

For example, say:

```
<?php

    // Grab the ID from URL, e.g. example.com/?p=123
    $post_id = $_GET['p'];

?>
```

How do I check if variable `$post_id` is a number, and a positive integer at that (i.e. 0-9, not a floating point number, fraction, or a negative number)?

**EDIT:** Can't use `is_int` 'cause `$_GET` returns a string. Think I need to use [`intval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333292/check-if-variable-is-a-number-and-positive-integer-in-php#comment28640215_19333292) or [`ctype_digit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3502877/1071413), with the latter seeming more appropriate. For example:

```
if( ctype_digit( $post_id ) ) { ... }
```

Comment: get the ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844916/best-way-to-check-for-positive-integer-php

Comment: Nitpicking here: $post_id is a string, because there are only strings in $_GET[]. ;-)

Comment: @stesch Just realized it based on one of the answers, back to working on the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @its_me Sorry, I was just joking. I know you want to know if the contents of the string would get you a number if converted with intval().

Comment: @stesch joking? where? you were right that `$_GET` returns a string. Also please take a look at the edit in the question and let me know which solution you think is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if a string input is a positive integer, i always use the function [ctype_digit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php). This is much easier to understand and faster than a regular expression.

```
if (isset($_GET['p']) && ctype_digit($_GET['p']))
{
  // the get input contains a positive number and is safe
}
```

Comment: You mean like `if( ctype_digit( $post_id ) ) { ... }` as seen in my question? If so, please add it to yours so that I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @its_me - Yes that will be right. To void warnings you can also test whether the variable is set at all, before you test it with `ctype_digit()`.

Comment: Remember, this will not work if your number has float point i.e 12.50

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:-

```
if( is_int( $_GET['id'] ) && $_GET['id'] > 0 ) {

   //your stuff here

}
```

Answer (score 2):

is_int is only for type detection. And request parameters are string by default. So it won't work. http://php.net/is_int

A type independent working solution:

```
if(preg_match('/^\d+$/D',$post_id) && ($post_id>0)){
   print "Positive integer!";
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what `/^\d+$/D` does there? Some explanation about the code would be nice.

Comment: About preg_match: php.net/preg_match

/^\d+$/ means: From the beginning to the end there are at least one \d(=number). The trailing D is required to not match against trailing \n-s. (I forgot at first the only positive requirement... I added a $post>0)

Comment: Just realized I could simply do `if( ctype_digit( $post_id ) ) { ... }`. What do you think about that? Good?

Comment: Yes it is fine. The only drawback that you have to ensure you use it only for strings. It can do strange things when it is called with a non-string.

Comment: And of course you need the $post_id>0 check if you adhere to positive numbers only.

Answer (score 2):

use ctype_digit but, for a positive number, you need to add the "> 0" check

```
if (isset($_GET['p']) && ctype_digit($_GET['p']) && ($_GET['p'] > 0))
{
  // the get input contains a positive number and is safe
}
```

in general, use ctype_digit in this way

```
if (ctype_digit((string)$var))
```

to prevent errors

Answer (score 1):

positive integer and greater that 0

```
if(is_int($post_id) && $post_id > 0) {/* your code here */}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is_numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.is-numeric.php) to check if a var is a number. You also have [is_int](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-int.php). To test if it's positive juste do something like if (var > 0).