# PHP Validating an input is between 0-10 and is a number?

Tags: php

I was supposed to build a script to alert the user if they input a non-numeric input or a value greater than 10.

I have this:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <p>Iterations:
    <input type="text" name="rows" size="5">
    <input type="submit" value="Loop">
    </p>
</form>
<table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#669999' align="center">

<?php

$rows = $_GET['rows'];

 for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
     if (is_numeric($i)) {
     echo "<tr><td>Iteration is $i</td></tr>";
     } 
 else {
     echo "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10.";
     }
 }


 ?>
```

But it will only return a list of Iteration is 1-10, I can't get it to iterate the number of times I input?

Edit: The loop is actually essential to this.

I'm building on a previous script that would loop like so if, say 5, were entered:

Iteration is 1

Iteration is 2

Iteration is 3

Iteration is 4

Iteration is 5

So this is why I am iterating it and looping it.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

**EDIT #2**

I've fixed it everyone.

```
<?php
 $rows = $_GET['rows'];
 $value = intval($rows);

 if (1 <= $value && $value <= 10) {
     for ( $i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++ ) { 
      echo "<tr><td>Iteration is $i</td></tr>";
   }

 } else {
    echo "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10.";
 }

?>
```

I've used a combination of $intval to assess the integer of $rows and compare it to see if it's between 1 and 10.

Then I looped it through according to the assignment.

We were supposed to use is_numeric but... this is much cleaner in my mind.

Thanks all!

I'll be answering this after work tomorrow.

Comment: You made my day. Why isn't it `is_numeric($_GET['rows']) && $_GET['rows']>0 && $_GET['rows']<11` ?

Comment: These errors notwithstanding, validating integer values with `is_numeric` is suboptimal because `is_numeric` also allows floating point and scientific notation. If you want "digits only" then use `ctype_digit` (or a regular expression).

Comment: @Jon yes, fair enough, but OP didn't mentioned that `rows` should be int

Comment: `is_numeric($i)`? You define `$i` just one line before as `$i = 1`!

Comment: Earlier I was trying to assign $rows to $_GET['rows'] and put if (is_numeric($rows)), but this didn't help any, I've kept it in case there's some way I can use it still.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333292/check-if-variable-is-a-number-and-positive-integer-in-php/19333347#19333347](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333292/check-if-variable-is-a-number-and-positive-integer-in-php/19333347#19333347)

Comment: Additionally, the is_numeric function is the one I'm supposed to be using.

Answer (score 3):

`intval` returns 0 if a non integer is passed to it. Then check it is between range.

```
 $rows = $_GET['rows'];

 if (($value = intval($rows)) !== 0 && 1 <= $value && $value <= 10) {
    echo "Number is ok";
 } else {
    echo "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10.";
 }
```

Without setting variable in if:

```
 $rows = $_GET['rows'];
 $value = intval($rows);

 if (1 <= $value && $value <= 10) {
    echo "Number is ok";
 } else {
    echo "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10.";
 }
```

`intval`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: Declaring variables in ifs is very bad idea.

Comment: This would just perform the same condition check on each iteration. Why is that necessary?

Comment: Why? There is nothing wrong with that at all? It only declares it for validation later in the if?

Comment: @ElonThan why is it a bad idea?!

Comment: @bwoebi Code like that is harder to read (you're checking condition or declaring variable?) and it's easier to make mistake.

Comment: @ElonThan well; here he's using a _temporary variable_, just for use in the if. That's a perfectly valid use case.

Comment: @ElonThan: Then how do you explain `while($row = mysqli...)` stuff?

Comment: @bwoebi It's valid but not good. There are many things that you can do (because they'll not lead to parse erros) but you shouldn't do, because anyone that will read that code will think only about finding and killing you. Also, you'll be one of that people if you'll return to your code after longer time.

Comment: @bwoebi: It's a matter of preference. Compared to assigning independently, this way you are saving (typing less) a `$value` -- 6 chars. That's not a whole lot of argument, so if the "verbose" version reads better to you then that's the one to use.

Comment: @AmalMurali I don't have to explain that, because it's normal and easy to read when you declare variable in loop. But you can't compare it to `if`, especially with few comparisons. We've got updated answer now, check it and tell which code is more readable?

Comment: @Jon it's not about chars; but I think it's a better indicator for the fact that the $variable is just designed to be used in the if?

Comment: @bwoebi: That could be a legit reason. Personally I don't think so because keeping methods short plus IDE live highlighting makes this indication redundant for me, but I can appreciate the argument.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this..And why are you iterating it.?

```
 $rows = $_GET['rows'];
 if (is_numeric($rows) && $rows <= 10 && $rows >= 1) {
    echo "Number is ok";
 } 
 else {
    echo "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 10.";
 }
```

Comment: Not well since negative values will pass (floats as well, but OP didn't mentioned about that)

Comment: @User016: Oh, you edited the answer in the meanwhile. I've removed my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast to `int` and use regular conditions:

```
$rows = (!empty($_GET['rows']) ? (int)$_GET['rows'] : 0);
//Cast it!                       ^^^^^

if ($rows >= 1 && $rows <= 10) {
    //We got a match!
} else {
    //We don't have a match!
}
```

***Note:** This will also turn `1.234` into `1`*

Comment: This will turn almost everything into `0`.

Comment: Accepting `abc` as valid input clearly violates the *alert the user if they input a non-numeric input* part of the spec.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Which could easily be fixed by placing **anything** inside the `else` clause.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: What if I enter `4chan`? No matter how you cut it, the `int` cast is a bad way to validate.

Comment: And you're even discarding actual zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 $rows = (isset($_GET['rows']) ? $_GET['rows'] : 0);

 if (is_numeric($rows) && $rows >= 1 && $rows <= 10) {
    echo "Ok";
 } 
 else {
    echo "Fail";
 }
```