# Is ctype_digit safe for post and get data integer validation in php?

Tags: php, validation, post, get

i want to know if [ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-digit.php) is safe and enough for post and get data (user input) integer validation?

**ctype_digit definition:**

```
  bool ctype_digit ( string $text )
  Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical.
```

Comment: `is_int()` on get/post data will always return `false`.

Comment: Post and get data come as String and we usually escape it (even if it come as int it would be converted). Ctype_digit looks like the exactly function we need, but it looks like a few users use it for validation, do you know why? Thank your for your time.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ah, good to know: _([is_int and GET or POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502854/is-int-and-get-or-post))_

Comment: ctype_* methods are meant to be checking values and not types. So yes, it's good to use them. Just make sure you always insert a string ;)

Answer (score 0):

It can be good enough for *positive* integers. But you can simply use the [filter functions](https://www.php.net/filter_input).

Comment: Thank you. Minding database ids, is there any need to use filters, or im good to go with ctype_digit (filters use more code, so i guess there`s no need for use it everytime if i can use another function)?

Comment: If you build DB queries correctly (i.e., prepared statements) you don't really *need* to validate input at all (except to avoid querying the DB with totally bogus data).